# Converting LinkedHashMap<String,MyClass> to Java Object

Tags: java, json, casting, jackson, pojo

How can I convert the JSON string like this:

```
{ "summary": {
    "totalMR":4.599000000000903E12,
    "totalMA":1.9174920000386694E11,
    "totalQA":5.1111111181E9,
    "totalQR":1.000020666115264E11
  },
  "result": [{},{}],
  "success":"true",
  "total":49
}
```

to a Java object. I went through many similar posts and implemented constructors but couldn't find the proper explanation of why I'm unable to De-serialize the JSON.

Am I doing anything wrong?

My Class:

```
public class expResponse {
private String success;
private String total;
private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> result;
private LinkedHashMap<String,SummaryResponse> summary;
// Constructor: public expResponse(){}
// Getter and Setter 
}

public class SummaryResponse {
private Float totalQR;
private Float totalQA;
private Float totalMR;
private Float totalMA;

public SummaryResponse(){}
// Setter and Getter
}
```

My Code:

```
private expResponse processResult(String result) throws IOException{
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
expResponse expResponseObj = 
objectMapper.readValue(result, expResponse.class);
return expResponseObj;
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to De-serialize the JSON"? Are you getting an exception? Missing data? Is your computer emitting blue smoke?

Comment: convertValue worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json you posted would not deserialize into a map of SummaryResponse objects, but rather an individual SummaryResponse object. To make your binding work, you would have to have json that looked something like this:

```
{
 ...
  'summary': {
    'summary1': {"totalMR":4.599000000000903E12,"totalMA":1.9174920000386694E11,"totalQA":5.1111111181E9,"totalQR":1.000020666115264E11}
    'summary2': {"totalMR":4.599000000000903E12,"totalMA":1.9174920000386694E11,"totalQA":5.1111111181E9,"totalQR":1.000020666115264E11}
  }
 ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to make your Java class conform to the json you provided, you simply need to change the declaration of summary:

```
private SummaryResponse summary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Field summary in your json is an object of type SummaryResponse and not a LinkedHashMap.

```
public class ExpResponse {
  private String success;
  private String total;
  private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> result;
  private Summary summary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have a problem in the code. Your input fails because it is not in the correct format. If you try to write the same values from an object with the same values to string you get something like:

```
{
   "success":"true",
   "total":"49",
   "result":null,
   "summary":{
      "one_summary":{
         "totalQR":2000.0,
         "totalQA":1500.0,
         "totalMR":1000.0,
         "totalMA":500.0
      }
   }
}
```

And the major difference is the one summary. This is because `summary` is a `map` and `maps` need a `key` for each `entryset`. That means that  `summary` is your map which has a `one_summary` key.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the SummaryResponse that can't be deserialised?

I guess your attributes should have the same name "totalMR", "totalMA"....
or you should use an annotation JsonProperty(value="totalMR") and so on.

Comment: This answer is not correct. His field names do match the names of the fields in the json document he provided.

Comment: At first the SummaryResponse fields were much different and named total_.... Don't remember the exact names. Anyway it was just a part of the answer and other answers cover the issue

Comment: @eric.v you can click on the "edited ... ago" link to see the revision history. All that changed was the indentation.

Comment: @eric.v is correct. The original version of the code had very different names for the attributes. My apologies. However, given the edit (we have to trust the OP), this answer is still not correct.